# DB2 revoke user privileges from a database from multiple users

Tags: db2, privileges, db2-luw, sql-revoke

I want to revoke all privileges from all users but one from a database.
DB2 10.5 LUW

I was thinking along the lines of:

```
 db2 "revoke all on database from user IN (select grantee from syscat.dbauth where grantee not IN 'SAFEUSER')"
```

but I can't get it to work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `ALL` clause in the [REVOKE (database authorities) statement](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000981.html).
You may generate the set of statements needed by the following select statement:

```
select 
  'REVOKE '
|| SUBSTR 
(
  CASE ACCESSCTRLAUTH WHEN 'N' THEN '' ELSE ', ACCESSCTRL' END 
||CASE BINDADDAUTH WHEN 'N' THEN '' ELSE ', BINDADD' END 
||CASE CONNECTAUTH WHEN 'N' THEN '' ELSE ', CONNECT' END 
--- add here expressions with all other *AUTH columns
, 2)
||' ON DATABASE FROM ' 
|| CASE 
     WHEN GRANTEE = 'PUBLIC' THEN ''
     WHEN GRANTEETYPE = 'U' THEN 'USER' 
     WHEN GRANTEETYPE = 'G' THEN 'GROUP' 
     WHEN GRANTEETYPE = 'R' THEN 'ROLE' 
   END
||' '||GRANTEE
from syscat.dbauth
WHERE 'Y' IN 
(
ACCESSCTRLAUTH, BINDADDAUTH, CONNECTAUTH
--- add here all other *AUTH columns separated by ','
)
AND  grantee <> 'SAFEUSER'
;
```

Comment: Does this remove the user entries or just set all privs to N?

Comment: Db2 will remove entries in `syscat.dbauth` is all the AUTH columns are set to `N`. Also for other privileges, you can generate similar statements from `sysibmadm.privileges`